# How to Keep Track of colem index when JTable has been Reordering?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i have jTable that has colems names like folow :-

```
columns = {"ID", "NAME", "PHONE"};
```

Contain values :

```
----------------------------
|ID |   NAME   |   PHONE   |
----------------------------
| 1 |   Adeeb  |   0750000 |
| 2 |   Jack   |   0777777 |
----------------------------
```

This jTable has ReorderingAllowed :

```
jTable1.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(true);
```

i have a button to get values from Colem "Name" :

```
   for (int k = 0; k < jTable1.getRowCount(); k++) {

        String qty = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(k, jTable1.getColumn("NAME").getModelIndex());
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name Is : " + qty);

    }
```

it is getting values As follows :

```
Name Is : Adeeb
Name Is : Jack
```

But if the user arranges the fields as in the following example:

```
------------------------------
|ID |   PHONE    |   Name    |
------------------------------
| 1 |   0750220  |    Adeeb  |
| 2 |   0777777  |    Jack   |
------------------------------
```

it is getting values As follows :

```
Name Is : 0750220
Name Is : 0777777
```

i need it to give me result like before so i need it to Keep Track the column "name" and getting value from it even if user re sort it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the data from the TableModel. The data in the model is not reordered.

```
String name = table.getModel.getValueAt(row, 2);
```

Or to get the data from the table you need to use:

```
int columnIndex = table.modelToView(2);
String name = table.getValueAt(row, columnIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixsed It By This :

```
TableColumnModel tcms = jTable1.getColumnModel();

    for (int k = 0; k < jTable1.getRowCount(); k++) {

    int location = tcms.getColumnIndex(model.getColumnName(1));

    String qty = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(k, location);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, qty);
}
```